# The name 'AutomationId' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, testing, ui-testing, white-framework

I have assembly with UI automation tests (White).

I've introduced a class with all Autination Id's to be reused in this assembly:

```
public static class AutomationId
{
    public static class Toolbar
    {
        public const string MyControl = "MyControlId";
    }
}
```

And now i'm trying to use it in my test class (the same assembly):

```
var control = mainWindow.Get<Button>(AutomationId.Toolbar.MyControl);
```

This code can be compiled locally. But on TeamCity I'm getting a such error:

```
The name 'AutomationId' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a C# 6 feature. Similar problem: [The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943593/the-name-nameof-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

I encountered this problem just now, which lead me here. My research indicates that you need to update Teamcity:

http://dave.ninja/2015/08/06/upgrading-teamcity-to-support-visual-studio-2015/

We still have to do this, as well. The post above shows a lot of solutions to issues that they encountered while upgrading. Didn't seem a too painful process.