# The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS 2013 with .Net Framework 4.6. I want to use new C# 6 features(For example `nameof`).But I couldn't found it.

[image]

Should I use VS 2015? Or higher .Net Framework?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot use C# 6 in VS2013.  You will need to upgrade to 2015

Comment: afaik, C# Language Feature releases go hand in hand with Visual Studio releases, and aren't backported.

Comment: You should still be able to use .Net Framework 4.6 in Visual Studio 2013, but as you already answered your own question, you need Visual Studio 2015 in order to use C# 6.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, to use C# 6 features, you need a C# 6 compiler. Visual Studio 2013 doesn't have a C# 6 compiler. Visual Studio 2015 does.

There have been Roslyn pre-releases for Visual Studio 2013, but they don't implement the final C# 6: they actually don't implement all the features, and what they do implement is different from the final C# 6 behaviour.

Comment: I'm using VS2015, update 2, and I just started seeing this issue today.  It used to work.  EDIT: Turns out there was a stupid syntax error in my program, and Visual Studio got confused and decided that it was because `nameof doesn't exist in the current context`. -- Very strange.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 - that was it for me too. A downstream syntax error (this was also in a static method, wonder if that's related) caused nameof() to not be recognized.

Answer (score 6):

yes you need to use Visual Studio 2015. It's not supported in VS 2013. Related link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx

Answer (score 6):

In pre-VS2015 you can add the following class to your solution and replace all instances of `nameof(` with `NameOf.nameof(() =>` as suggested in [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib
{
    public class NameOf
    {
        public static String nameof<T>(Expression<Func<T>> name)
        {
            MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression)name.Body;
            return expressionBody.Member.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrible solution though.

Comment: Or you can buy me VS 2015 :)

Answer (score 6):

Installing this nuget package fixed it for my project.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to use C#6 in VS2013. The compiler will not understand the new C# 6 syntax you are trying to use.
[How can I add C# 6.0 to Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462553/how-can-i-add-c-sharp-6-0-to-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when using [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), I just switched to .NET Core instead of .NET 4.7.X.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this error in Teamcity, make the following changes to build step to correct it.

1. Open your MSBuild step in teamcity
2. Change the MSBuild version to Microsoft Build Tools 2015
3. Change the MSBuild ToolVersion to 14.0

Answer (score 0):

1. In "Package Manager Console" execute "install-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers" with your respective project selected.
2. Ensure "C# Language Level" is "C# 6.0" in your project settings.

Comment: It's Microsoft.Net.Compiler**s**. Not Microsoft.Net.Compiler. (I can't edit solution below 6 characters)
Additionally, after installation C# 6.0 still doesn't exists in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error and are using the latest .Net it could be because you are using the name of something that isn't a .Net Type. Here's an example:

Original with need to replace HardCoded "BaseUrl".

```
IConfiguration settingsConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
Settings = Options.Create(new Settings
{
  BaseUrl = settingsConfig.GetSection("BaseUrl").Value
});
```

This causes the error and it doesn't work because the BaseUrl doesn't exist in context:

```
IConfiguration settingsConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
Settings = Options.Create(new Settings
{
  BaseUrl = settingsConfig.GetSection(nameof(BaseUrl)).Value
});
```

You need to fully qualify or specify a .Net Type that exists, eg:

```
Settings = Options.Create(new Settings
{
  BaseUrl = settingsConfig.GetSection(nameof(Settings.BaseUrl)).Value
});
```